# Is there a mouse gestures add-on for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, mouse-gestures

With the release of chrome 3.0 I am again considering switching to chrome as my default browser. The only thing stopping me, and it has been stopping me since chrome 1 came out, is the lack of the mouse gestures add-on that i have in firefox.

Mouse Gestures have become so routine for me that I simply can't use another browser that doesn't have them. There are ways to kinda emulate mouse gestures using 3rd party programs like gmote but they are not the same and not quite as good. I know that chrome developer has add-ins but I haven't been able to find a mouse-gestures one. I'm fairly confident that many people want one.

So, does a mouse gestures add-on exist for chrome? bonus points if there is a firebug/xmarks add-in as well!

Comment: Related, but Linux specific: http://superuser.com/q/134268/1087

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mouse gestures are one of the reasons why I'm still using Firefox. There are some programs that can replace the mouse gestures plugin such as

- [GMote](http://www.handform.net/gmote.php)
- [StrokeIt](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/)

Added bonus is that you can then use mouse gestures with any program.

Comment: It's not always a "bonus", though, depending on your use.

Comment: Well then you can easily deactivate them for everything but.

Answer (score 2):

[StrokeIt!](http://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/) provides systemwide mouse gestures - including inbuilt support for Chrome, as well as it's fantastic customisation.

Answer (score 0):

Add-ons aren't available in the public release of Chrome yet. They are available in the developer versions, however.

Unfortunately, this means that there aren't many add-ons being developed yet. It will be coming soon, though.